# Python 2.7 - How to check if SHIFT-Key or CTRL+Key is pressed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, keypress, ctrl

I wrote a small routine in python 2.7, which waits for some time (say, 10 minutes) but immediately exits if a key is pressed by the the user.

I'm on Windows (7, 64-bit), so I tried using the msvcrt library:

```
import sys
import msvcrt
from time import sleep

   def sleep_sec(secstosleep, allowskip = True):
       waitinterval_ms = 0.050
       nwaits = int(secstosleep * 1000 / waitinterval)

       sys.stdout.write("\n    Sleeping for %s seconds. You can press CTRL-F12 to skip.\n\n" % secstosleep)
       for sl in range(0, nwaits + 1):
           sleep(waitinterval_ms)
           if allowskip:
               # Check if User has pressed CTRL-F12 to stop waiting
               if = msvcrt.kbhit():
                   kp = msvcrt.getch()
                   if kp == '\xe0':
                        print "\a"  # Beep once
                        sys.stdout.write("\nSleep interrupted by User\n")
                        break
```

In effect it works quite well, except for the fact that it will break if the user hits either F12, F11 or Cursor Up key: I found out that if I press F12, getch() will return the '\xe0', but it seems the same code is also returned by the other mentioned keys; no way to trap CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, etc.

I would like to force the user pressing CTRL-F12, instead, to avoid quitting the wait by inadvertently hitting one of those keys.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to intercept CTRL, ALT or SHIFT being pressed along with another key?

Thanks in advance,
Max - Italy

Comment: `waitinterval` isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `msvcrt` manual for `msvcrt.getch()`:

> [..] If the pressed key was a special function key, this will return '\000' or '\xe0'; the next call will return the keycode.

Just call `getch()` again to get the actual keycode

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel, Now it works perfectly!. Max.

Answer (score 6):

I will suggest you to use [**`keyboard`**](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module. It has a lot of features and is pretty simple to use.  You can also use it to detect keypresses. Examples:
If you want to detect key `a`:

```
import keyboard as kb
while True:
    if kb.is_pressed("a"):break
```

You can also use it to detect combinations. For example , if you want to check if `a` and `b` are pressed at the same time:

```
import keyboard as kb
while True:
    if kb.is_pressed("a+b"):break
```

So , you can use to to detect if `ctrl` and `f12` are pressed:

```
import keyboard as kb
while True:
    if kb.is_pressed("ctrl+f12"):break
```

A sample according to your posted code:

```
import sys
import keyboard as kb
import time
def sleep_sec(secstosleep,allowskip=True):
    t = time.time() #getting time in sec
    sys.stdout.write("\n    Sleeping for %s seconds. You can press CTRL-F12 to skip.\n\n"% secstosleep)
    if allowskip:
        while time.time() - t <= secstosleep: #while current time(in sec) - t is less than secstosleep
            if kb.is_pressed("ctrl+f11"): #if ctrl and f12 are pressed
                print "\a"
                sys.stdout.write("\nSleep interrupted by User\n")
                quit(0)
sleep_sec(10*60) # 10*60 == 10 min
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this needs be run as root on linux :(

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Daniel, I've modified my code like this:

```
import sys
import msvcrt
from time import sleep

def sleep_sec(secstosleep, allowskip = True):
   waitinterval_ms = 0.050
   nwaits = int(secstosleep * 1000 / waitinterval)

   sys.stdout.write("\n    Sleeping for %s seconds. You can press CTRL-F12 to skip.\n\n" % secstosleep)
   for sl in range(0, nwaits + 1):
       sleep(waitinterval_ms)
       if allowskip:
           # Check if User has pressed CTRL-F12 to stop waiting
           if = msvcrt.kbhit():
               kp = msvcrt.getch()
               if kp == '\xe0':
                    kp += msvcrt.getch()

               if kp == '\xe0\x8a':    # \x8a is the keycode for CTRL-F12
                    print "\a"  # Beep once
                    sys.stdout.write("\nSleep interrupted by User\n")
                    break
```

I've also noticed that different keycodes are returned for F12, CTRL-F12 and SHIFT-F12, so keystrokes can be easily recognized.

Thanks again, Daniel!

Max.