# [Solved]Python detect Ctrl+R[Edited]

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I've been trying to make a program that when you press Ctrl+R, it will run another program and kill itself and the other program will start the main program using a subprocess. Popen, the program could not detect the whole key, only Ctrl was detected when I was using keyboard.read_key()

```
def _restart():
    while keyboard.read_key()!="^R":
        pass
    subpro.Popen([r"C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe","restarter.py"])
leave()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses)

Comment: @ewokx that's not working :(

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692526/python-2-7-how-to-check-if-shift-key-or-ctrlkey-is-pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using keyboard.read_key(), you can use a keyboard hook that listens for key events. This will allow you to detect combined keypresses like Ctrl+R.

example code:

```
import keyboard
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import time

def restart_program():
    # Terminate the current program
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)

    # Start the restarter script
    subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe", "restarter.py"])

def on_key_event(event):
    if event.name == 'r' and event.event_type == 'down' and keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
        restart_program()

# Hook the keyboard events
keyboard.hook(on_key_event)

# Keep the program running
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```